# Swagger 2.0 - How to Define an Embedded Object

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I want to define an object with a key and a value but can't figure out how to define it as a property in a swagger 2.0 definition.  Frankly, I am not sure if this is even possible if one wants to be able to define strongly typed clients.  However, I figure I'd ask to see if this is even possible/allowable.

Basically, I want to be able to store the following object:

```
{ "currencies": 
  {  "usd" : 1.10,
     "eur" : 2.25
  }
}
```

But I don't want usd, and eur to have to be defined in the schema.  I can do the below but I don't want usd or eur to be predefined.  I want it to accept any value for the keys of the object.

```
 "Product": {
    "properties": {
        "currencies": {
                    "type": "currencyObj"               
                },
            }
     }, 
  },
  "currencyObj": {
     "id": "currencyObj",
     "properties": {
          "eur": {
             "type": "float"
          },
          "usd": {
            "type": "float"
          }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swagger 2.0 allows you to define a [string to type mapping](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#model-with-mapdictionary-properties), you need to use additionalProperties. Use following notation to define a map  :

```
"currencyObj": {
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "number"
  }
}
```